# Filter new mail based on action performed on previous ones of the same conversation

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I keep receiving emails sent to mailing lists which I subscribe, some of them are interested to me while other are not.

So, I want to set up the filter which mark an email as unimportant when I mark as unimportant or delete the first mail from the same conversation.

By doing so, I won't be spammed by something I'm not interested in but still receive others interesting mail from the same address.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Instead of deleting or filtering the first conversation in a thread, you can "mute" the thread. In your inbox view, select the email conversation you'd like to mute, and then select `More > Mute`. This will prevent the thread from popping up again.
2. Doing the same thing (selecting the thread and then clicking `More`), you can select "Filter messages like these." This will bring up the filters page, populated first with the senders email. You can add criteria such as:

> ```
> Sender: xxxx@xxxx.com
> Subject: xxxx
> Has the words: xxxxx
> ```

Using the right combination might help future threads from hitting your inbox.